# Django matplotlib tkinter.TclError: NULL main window

Tags: django, matplotlib, tkinter, pdflatex

I've been working with matplotlib.pyplot, pdflatex and django to create an app that retrieves data from a database, createspng  charts based on that data and compile a tex file that has that images. I create four kinds of charts, each one associated with a function:

```
#A bar/line with a rezised chart
plt.figure(figsize=(16.0, 10.0))
plt.bar(y_pos, values)
plt.plot(areas, standardValues)
plt.clf()

# A barchart with resized chart
plt.figure(figsize=(16.0, 10.0))
plt.bar(y_pos, diferrenceValues)
plt.clf()

# 10 histogram with distribution chart
shape, loc, scale = stats.lognorm.fit(hours_per_program, floc=0)
x_fit = np.linspace(data.min(), data.max(), 100)
hours_per_program_fit = stats.lognorm.pdf(x_fit, shape, loc=loc, scale=scale)
ax.hist(data, N_bins)
plt.clf()

# And 10 side bar charts
plt.barh(r1, data1, barHeight)
plt.barh(r2, data2, barHeight)
plt.barh(r3, data3, barHeight)
plt.clf()
```

The functions for each kind of chart is called in that order and that number of timer. So when I generate the pdf for the first time

```
...
File "/home/me/docs/project/t1/client/views.py", line 1359, in generatePdf
lineBarChart(areas_names, areas_program_hours, areas_standard_value, "cliente/static/img")
File "/home/me/docs/project/t1/client/chartGenerator.py", line 45, in lineBarChart
plt.figure(figsize=(16.0, 10.0))
File "/home/me/docs/project/t1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 548, in figure
**kwargs)
File "/home/me/docs/project/t1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 161, in new_figure_manager
return cls.new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, fig)
File "/home/me/docs/project/t1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py", line 1053, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
icon_img = Tk.PhotoImage(file=icon_fname)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3397, in __init__
Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3353, in __init__
self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: NULL main window
```

So tkinter, which i presume is what matplotlib works with to generate the images throws this exception, that there is no main window, I dont really understand why this happens, I generate 22 charts with no problem, but at the time I need to call the functions again, I cant resize , nor generate the charts because there is no tkinter window.
I would really appreciate some help, i have been fighting with this problem for days now I could not find the solution.
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: I would try to use a different backend, for example SVG.

Comment: This fixed it for me, thanks a lot!.

Comment: For reference to change the backend use import matplotlib.pyplot as plt and then plt.switch_backend('SVG')